# Combinatorial applications of diamond lemma

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, rewriting-systems

Recently, I found the following presentation by Darij Grinberg about applications of diamond lemma. Here is the link:

[http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/diamond-talk.pdf](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/%7Egrinberg/algebra/diamond-talk.pdf)

It seems to be very interesting tool for combinatorial problems (which deals with some process). I want to learn more about it and I am interested in examples of combinatorial applications of the diamond lemma.
I also find some examples (including algebraic examples) here

https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2009/11/20/the-diamond-lemma/

Comment: A lot of authors use the diamond lemma in their proofs, but rather than spelling it out as a lemma, they incorporate its (short) proof into the proof of whatever they're actually trying to prove. For example, spot the diamond lemma implicit in Section 5 of [Glânffrwd P. Thomas, *On a construction of Schützenberger*](https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(77)90024-3). Another place where this is done is the proof of Proposition 5.9 in ...

Comment: ... [Pavel Galashin, Darij Grinberg, Gaku Liu, *Refined dual stable Grothendieck polynomials and generalized Bender-Knuth involutions*, arXiv:1509.03803v2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.03803v2) (there is an [ancillary file](https://arxiv.org/src/1509.03803v2/anc/groth1alt.pdf) where the diamond lemma is actually spelt out and proven, but we ended up removing it from the published version due to the space it took up).